# Where's the cheapest place in the world for a beginner to learn diving?

Tags: budget, where-on-earth, destinations, diving

Would it mostly be in Southeast Asia? Or somewhere else?

In response to this Q being "put on hold" for being too broad, let me add the following:

Include only cost of equipment rental and lessons. Exclude cost of getting there, cost of food, cost of lodging.

Comment: Is there a particular qualification that you're hoping to get?

Comment: And does cheap include getting there from a specific location?

Comment: It'd be useful to specify which certification - PADI, Dive Master etc that you're after...

Comment: As he's a self-proclaimed beginner, the answer is almost certainly PADI Open Water.

Comment: The Bay Islands in Honduras were famous for cheap diving when I was backpacking around Central America a few years ago, but I don't know if it's as cheap as Southeast Asia.

Comment: including the expense of food and lodging makes this question even more broad!

Comment: Voting to reopen, the close reason "too many possible answers" makes no sense when asking absolute cheapest? Prove to me that many places offer the exact same minimum price. @KennyLJ: You have put very very little effort into this question. Read the comments to see the difficulties this causes. People have already put way more effort into their answers so please read them and tell us what you want? Just your first dive? PADI open water? Any qualification at all? Want to see coral? Fish? Anything? Some locations there's literally nothing to see.

Comment: @Dirty-flow: Really? Then you must be able to give us examples of one place with super low diving courses but not so cheap living expenses, and also vice-versa.

Comment: @hippietrail your previous comment actually shows that the question is too broad. and when we add food and accomodation - Some people are probably ready to sleep under any bridge and not to eat 2-3 days, I will prefer to stay in 3* hotel... and also - prices change! and that's why shopping question are off topic here.

Comment: Doesn't matter. The person sleeping under the bridge will still find Thailand cheaper than Norway. We have long supported "cheapest" questions, "shopping" questions are about looking for products. That means we don't support recommending diving companies, not that we don't support finding the cheapest destination.

Comment: this is an old question but I thought i'd mention that Utila, Honduras is very well known for this as well. It compares quite a bit to my time in Koh Tao, and at least a couple shops on the island are super professional.

Comment: Cheapest? Is a dangerous term to be primary goal looking for training.

Comment: @hippietrail - Would like your "feedback" to improve similar question related to Surfing http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3385/if-the-diving-question-of-a-similar-format-is-allowed-why-is-surfing-not-allowe

Comment: @hippietrail Free is the cheapest. The OP _does not state_ what kind of diving he wants to learn. Equipment could be anything from full scuba to fins and a snorkel. Come to my place in Virginia and I'll teach you to dive for free.

Answer (score 17):

The answer is almost certainly **Thailand**, in particular [Ko Tao](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ko_Tao), the PADI factory of the world.  An end-to-end course that gets you the standard PADI Open Water license will set you back roughly 9800 baht (~$310 at time of writing); if you're happy with the far more limited PADI Scuba Diver course, you can complete that for 7000 baht (~$225) at [this randomly chosen dive shop](http://www.planetscuba.com/scubadiver.html). Chuck in food and accommodation for around 1000 baht/day all-in for 3-4 days (you can squeeze by for less if you're <s>a cheapskate</s> *frugal*), and you can complete your course for under $500.

A close second is Malaysia, where diving is about the same price due to furious competition, but food and accommodation are generally pricier.  I'd imagine the Philippines are in roughly the same price bracket as well.  Diving in Indonesia is generally *not* as affordable simply because the diving off Bali is not that great and the places with great diving (Bunaken etc) are in harder-to-reach locations.

All that said, diving is one of those things where you definitely don't want to look for price alone, this is life support equipment we're talking about here and you want to make sure it's properly maintained.  (When I lived in Singapore, I ended up buying my own gear, just so I could maintain it myself.)  So do your homework and pay a little extra to find a dive shop with a clue, here's a [handy article](http://www.scubaguru.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60%3ahow-to-select-a-dive-shop&catid=41&Itemid=54) with some tips. (TL;DR: Check online reviews, go visit, chat with the instructors and look for certifications, general cleanliness, gear appearance and maintenance schedule.)

Comment: Quality of instruction can vary a lot too! Someone who's done a rigorous course in a colder location tends to be a much better diver early on than someone who's done their Open Water somewhere warm + relaxed...

Comment: Yup, I'm a CMAS Nordic Diver myself, and after getting accustomed to 4C water and zero visibility, it was piss-easy to dive in the tropics.  Many recommend doing at least the theory at home and only the practical dives while traveling.

Comment: It's a bit rough calling everybody willing to embark upon adventures with less wealth than yourself a "cheapskate". By this measure most of the nice local people in these places are also cheapskates. Remember there's plenty of rich people who might consider you a cheapskate too. Now the advice about how well maintained the gear is is an *extremely* important point however so +1 but offering some advice on how to know tell whether a place has good gear might also help.

Comment: If you're about to burn $500 on a PADI Open Water license, plus rather a lot more to get to Ko Tao in the first place, you're by definition wealthy enough to have disposable income!  But all I meant is that 1000 baht/day is a workable minimum budget for most *travellers* in Thailand, you need to make some conscious sacrifices to manage below that. Obviously actually living in the country is different, the Thai minimum wage is still under 10k/mo.

Comment: Getting a qualification might be money to burn for some people and might be an investment for other people. I've certainly met my share of people that got PADI certification in cheap places and went on to become diving teachers, etc. I'm personally pretty far down the budget scale but constantly meet travellers on much lower budgets having a great time, especially young people from developing countries that still find a way to fund their travels. I find these people inspirational.

Comment: @hippietrail There's often a big difference in competence between someone who does a warm water PADI with a view to a dive master then does tens of dives in short succession to get enough for the qualification start, vs someone who does a warm water PADI then does nothing for a long time...

Comment: @Gagravarr: Well that's a good warning to include in an answer or warn the OP that they might want to clarify in the question, but as it stands they're only asking about cheapest and that is objectively answerable. Just more reasons these low-effort 1.5 sentence questions are not the best ones to ask.

Answer (score 6):

Alicante, Spain. You can get [some offers](http://es.groupalia.com/descuentos-alicante/oferta-buceo-cursos-pelicar-alicante.html) from €130 for a two-day course. Normal prices are a bit higher (€200), but if you just want to get the PADI certificate, this is the cheapest way I've found. In Alicante most people speak fluent english and sleeping and eating each day is about €25 if you go to a hostel or similar and cook your own food. Also, if you live in Europe or even in America, the flight is much cheaper to Alicante than to any south Asian country. The sea is the Mediterranean, not so impressive as the Thailand seas, but not too bad.

Comment: That offer appears to be for the PADI Scuba Diver course, which doesn't permit you to dive except one-on-one with a divemaster, and is thus not usually considered a "real" diving certification like Open Water. http://www.padi.com/scuba/padi-courses/diver-level-courses/view-all-padi-courses/scuba-diver/

Comment: May be it's true @jpatokal, but the op is not asking for a "Open Water", he's asking for a place "to learn diving" which is a more open question than a place to get this specific certification.

Answer (score 5):

Lake Malawi, Malawi it's $350 for the open water padi cert at [aquanuts](http://www.aquanutsdivers.com/). In terms of accommodation next to the dive shop is [Kande Beach](http://kandebeach.com/), if you have your own tent $5 a night otherwise it's a cabin for $15 per person per night. The food is cheap and so is the beer.

So unless you bring a tent you are looking at $500.

Answer (score 4):

### Cheaper Is Not the Way

For the purpose of safety I will start off by repeating what others have already mentioned: **looking for the cheapest place to learn something potentially life-threatening is probably not a good idea**. Ask yourself how these places can afford to charge less for the organisation of an activity, and the maintenance of gear, both of which are inherently expensive.
If costs are reduced by cutting the materials and maintenance budget, then you'd probably not want to be trained in such a club.

### Go Local with Group-Buys

When I first qualified in 2004, the average price for a first scuba diving certification, be it PADI or CMAS, oscillated between 300€ and 400€, back home in Italy. This included renting gear, learning materials, pool training and two or three sea dives (excluding accommodation). However, the recent boom of deal-of-the-day, group-buys and other similar websites has reduced prices of such activities dramatically. **You will most probably find a local dive club offering cheap rates** for open water certifications on Groupon, for example. [Here is a randomly-picked offer](http://www.groupon.com/deals/abyss-scuba-1) at 125$ for Open-Water PADI. Beware the link will inevitably expire soon, but you can do more research yourself.

The main advantage here is that you cut out travel and accommodation costs, since you wont be flying to the Pacific in order to take the course. Obviously, unless you live in places where the seaside offers amazing flora, fauna and landscape, you might have to settle for cold-water dives in quarries (yes UK residents, I am talking to you!). However I would say that this is what you get when looking for the cheapest deal.

Comment: I agree that one should consider factors other than--such as safety as you suggest. But I asked this question with a deliberate narrow focus on price, in part so that I'd keep it within the scope of SE (and render the question 'answerable').

Answer (score 0):

South Africa offers Open Water Diver courses in Range of R2000 - R6000 ($200 -$600). Depending on training organisation, location, time of year, additional options, etc.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more for your answer?

Answer (score -4):

Try DJL on Koh Tao.  www.davyjoneslocker.asia  They were excelent.  The equipment I used looked brand new and the instructor was really patient.  Talking afterwards to friends who did thier PADI course elsewhere (and paid a lot more)  I got the impression the training I got was much more detailed.