# Comparison website for scuba diving prices?

Tags: budget, online-resources, tips-and-tricks, diving

Is there a way to compare scuba diving prices at different locations around the world? I think the price for one scuba dive when you are already certified is quite comparable. I know that usually at the same location the prices don't vary too much, but between different places or countries sometimes even 10x. Tripadvisor gives reviews, but usually not the prices and one can't compare easily. I think this information is quite useful for people who scuba dive.

Comment: A shore dive will always be cheaper than a boat dive, and a dive with your own equipment is normally cheaper than one where you rent everything, so I fear there may be too many variables for a simple comparison

Comment: True, this information is useful, but I miss the function to quickly compare the prices across locations and countries. One might compare just shore dives, or something like that. When planning a diving trip and looking for a certain budget it might be interesting.

Comment: Perhaps you might set up just such a site in the Cloud...

Comment: It was part of my reason to ask here, if it makes sense at all. Any suggestions what platform or style?

Comment: Not a duplicate, but you'll likely find this interesting: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21435/wheres-the-cheapest-place-in-the-world-for-a-beginner-to-learn-diving/

Comment: would that be helpful? https://www.bookyourdive.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shamelessly converting [@RoflcoptrException's comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57698/comparison-wesite-for-scuba-diving-prices/59845#comment123717_57698) in a answer, [Book Your Dive](https://www.bookyourdive.com/) is a website which allows you to compare diving prices by location ([say for example in Indonesia](https://www.bookyourdive.com/in/indonesia)), and [by package deals](https://www.bookyourdive.com/packages). They even have [a blog post comparing resort packages with liveaboards](https://www.bookyourdive.com/blog/2015/12/8/dive-resort-or-liveaboard).

Comment: Thief! You just wanted to earn a hat!

Comment: Thanks RoflcoptrException, it looks like www.bookyourdive.com allows to search by country and that helps much. I still miss the feature to search by other things, such as if there are wrecks, ... But I consider my question answered, but I'm not going to give that to JoErNanO ;)